# Changing array value from string to int jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to change value of my array if I've got `["-2", -1, 0, 1, 2]`. I take data from text box, i need to have array of int instead of this with one string at the begining. I tried `parseInt(array)` and `eval(array)` but nothing is working. Thanks

Comment: how about `array[0] = +array[0];`

Comment: or `["-2", -1, 0, 1, 2].map(Number)`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/85rhpznd/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Unary +](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) can be used to convert its operand to a number:

```
array[0] = +array[0];
```

If you want to convert all strings in the array you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
array = array.map( Number );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't parse whole arrays, just elements from them. In your case `parseInt(array[0])`. This will parse an element at position 0 from your array (your first element).

**EDIT:**

Parsing to other number systems:

```
// Numbers with a leading 0 use a radix of 8 (octal)
var example = parseInt('0101');
// Numbers that start with 0x use a radix of 16 (hexidecimal)
var example = parseInt('0x0101');
// Numbers starting with anything else assumes a radix of 10
var example = parseInt('101');
// Or you can specify the radix, in this case 2 (binary)
var example = parseInt('0101', 2);
```

**SOURCE:** http://www.apkapps.link/questions/810611/why-do-we-need-to-use-radix

Answer (score 0):

Before using each element, you could always just run a `parseInt()` on it so that you don't have to worry about the number being a string or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make sure everything is numeric you can map everything to the `Number()` function:

```
[-1,0,1,3,4].map(Number)
```

However, that will leave "1.23" as 1.23.

To turn everything to INTs you cannot just map everything to `parseInt()` directly because map will actually pass multiple parameters and parseInt will use the extra paramenters to [incorrectly] define the radix. To make it work with `parseInt` you need to return a new function that calls parse with just the first parameter:

```
function mapParseInt(x) {
    return parseInt(x,10);
}

["-2", -1, 0, 1, 2.2].map(mapParseInt);
```

Or with an ES2015 fat arrow function:

```
["-2", -1, 0, 1, 2.2].map( x => parseInt(x,10) )
```

Answer (score 0):

To turn everything to INTs you cannot just map everything to parseInt() directly because map will actually pass multiple parameters and parseInt will use the extra paramenters to [incorrectly] define the radix. To make it work with parseInt you need to return a new function that calls parse with just the first parameter:
 http://www.azar.in/questions/810611/why-do-we-need-to-use-radix